# Enumerate using python

Tags: python

I'm a new coder and am currently trying to write a piece of code that, from an opened txt document, will print out the line number that each piece of information is on. 
I've opened the file and striped it of all it's commas. I found online that you can use a function called enumerate() to get the line number. However when I run the code instead of getting numbers like 1, 2, 3 I get information like: 0x113a2cff0. Any idea of how to fix this problem/what the actual problem is? The code for how I used enumerate is below.

```
my_document = open("data.txt")
readDocument = my_document.readlines()
invalidData = []
for data in readDocument:
    stripDocument = data.strip()
    if stripDocument.isnumeric() == False:
        data = (enumerate(stripDocument))
        invalidData.append(data)
```

Comment: What is `readDocument`? In any case, `enumerate` would be used something like `for i, data in enumerate(readDocument):`. This gives you the loop counter, `i`, and the `data` you would get by normal iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Read document is me opening the file and then reading the lines of it. I will update that in my post for clarification.

Comment: What do you intend to use the loop counter for? My first comment is correct in how to use `enumerate`; what you're seeing is the memory address of the iterator. But what is not clear is what you intend to do with the counter

Comment: I'm trying to keep track of which lines of the data file, contains data that isn't numeric, and then later on print off the line numbers along with their corresponding non-numeric data.

Comment: Your question clearly demonstrates that you did not spend the time to examine examples and understand the proper and normal usage of `enumerate`. Nor did you discover the proper and normal way of opening files. This sort of research is required prior to posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry about that sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, start by opening the document and already reading its content, and it's a good practice to use `with`, as it closes the document after the use. The `readlines` function gathers all the lines (this assumes the `data.txt` file is in the same folder as your `.py` one:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

After, use enumerate to add index to the lines, so you can read them, use them, or even save the indexes:

```
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    print(index, line)
```

As last point, if you have breaklines on your `data.txt`, the lines will contain a `\n`, and you can remove them with the `line.strip()`, if you need.

The full code would be:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    print(index, line.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm new to coding so learning new and better coding practices is quite helpful.

Comment: @Dyland, if you find my answer as the right one for you question, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Taking your problem statement:

> trying to write a piece of code that, from an opened txt document, will print out the line number that each piece of information is on

You're using `enumerate` incorrectly as @roganjosh was trying to explain:

```
with open("data.txt") as my_document:
    for i, data in enumerate(my_document):
        print(i, data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, and the help!

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it now, you're not removing the commas. The `strip()` method without arguments only deletes whitespaces leading and trailing the line. If you only want the data, this would work:

```
invalidData = []
for row_number, data in enumerate(readDocument):
    stripped_line = ''.join(data.split(','))
    if not stripped_line.isnumeric():
        invalidData.append((row_number, data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to enumerate a list. This will return a list of tuples containing the index first, then the line string. Like this:

```
(0, 'first line')
```

Your `readDocument` is a list of the lines, so it might be a good idea to name it accordingly.

```
lines = my_document.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    print i, line
```